# HQL Query - Part of String matches with part of String

Tags: hql

As mentioned in subject, I am trying to match partial of one string with partial of other string.

I am using HQL for querying.

**Eg.** "mycar" should be matching with "carpool". Because "car" is there in "carpool".

```
query = "select j from Part p, Job j join p.partNumbers numbers where p.id = j.part.id and numbers LIKE CONCAT('%',:partNumber,'%') and p.forRepair = true";

jobs = entityManager.createQuery( query, Job.class )
           .setParameter( "partNumber", searchValue )
           .getResultList();
```

In above query, It works only in certain cases.

**match** : "2222" -----> "222222"

**Doesn't match**: "a22" --->  "2222222"

Any suggestion, or any useful resource I can find useful in this case?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you want to find out if they have any letters in common? Or only those that are at the end or the beginning of the search string? I.e. should "mycar" also match "cars"?

Comment: Letters in common anywhere in String.

Comment: is there a minimum length?

Comment: In the does not match what is actualy your part number ? 22 or 2222222 ? If it is the second one than it is prettey obvious why it does not match. They don|t have common string.

Comment: I am new to pattern matching. So, not sure. Yeah, I need to set minimum length for matching. Any suggestions about length? Also, what are other parameters I need to take care and what it should be? Thanks and really appreciated for your time.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I am focusing on second example. I want it to be matched by not considering 'a' in first String. It should even match even there are some characters after 22 in first String.

Comment: @JaiminPatel  so your part number in this case is actualy 22 ? And you can confirm that the ID is passed correctly and that forRepair flag is true.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov "forRepair" flag is working properly and getting exactly what I am looking for.
My part number is "2222222" in database. I am using "a22" for searching. It is not matching anywhere in "222222". Stll, I want this record.
What I am thinking is , if user make any mistake in search term, still it should return a data from database. You see my point, right?

Comment: You can not use a22. You can use 22 for searching , but not the a22. Get it ?

Comment: If I understand correctly when you are seaarching a22 it is 22 that is your part number. Right ?

Comment: Yeah. I know. But, I want to use "a22" to get search result. There should be a way to search for similar pattern matching. I am looking for that way in HQL/Hibernate.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Right..

Comment: @JaiminPatel  This is a very custom behaviour you are looking for. SQL does not know for you where one word ends and one word starts. You need to be capable with better presision to tell it what are you looking for.

Comment: If you have some sort of pattern than you can consider using it to extract the two words. Fore example if you know that your part number is numeric and the front and the trail is alphanumeric than you can easily divide it into three words and then search by the words you want to include in the search.  But without telling the SQL what to search for it is not smart enough.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Totally agree with you. But where user can make mistake, we don't know. Right. User can type "a22" or "22a" for searching. Then how to handle this case in Hibernate? Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I just found temporary solution. Usually people make mstakes in the beginning or in the end of the string, I think. So, I neglect first two characters and last two characters for searching. Thanks again for your precious time.